# How to interpret torch.where() output when x , y are not given?

Tags: python, pytorch

I understand the output of torch.where() as per the content mentioned in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html).
However, I do not understand the output it produces when x and y are not given as show below (the dimensionality of this output keeps varying though the shape of x remains the same). Can someone help me understand?

```
y = torch.ones(3, 2)
x = torch.randn(3, 2)
print(x)
----------------------------
tensor([[-0.0022,  0.4871],
        [ 0.0788,  0.2937],
        [ 0.1909, -2.1636]])
----------------------------
print(torch.where(x > 0, x, y))
----------------------------
tensor([[1.0000, 0.4871],
        [0.0788, 0.2937],
        [0.1909, 1.0000]])
----------------------------
print(torch.where(x > 0))

(tensor([0, 1, 1, 2]), tensor([1, 0, 1, 0]))
```

Comment: From the documentation: `torch.where(condition)` is identical to `torch.nonzero(condition, as_tuple=True)`.

Answer (score 2):

This version of `torch.where` intend to return satisfying element indexes.

```
print(f"Y={torch.where(x > 0)[0].numpy()}")
print(f"X={torch.where(x > 0)[1].numpy()}")
--------------------------------
Y=[0 1 1 2]
X=[1 0 1 0]
```

Here you can better see coordinates of positives in matrix.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a few examples of different shaped tensors (including 3 and 4 dimension tensors), I understood that when only the boolean condition is passed but not the x and y parameters to torch.where() function, it outputs separate tensors, one for each of the dimensions with the corresponding indices of the elements that meet the boolean condition.

So, in the above output ---- (tensor([0, 1, 1, 2]), tensor([1, 0, 1, 0])) ---- tensor([0, 1, 1, 2]) represents the indices of 1st dimension for all the elements that satisfy the condition x > 0, and the tensor([1, 0, 1, 0]) represents the indices of 2nd dimension of the same elements.